# Get value from EditText, CheckBox, and TextView in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have editText, checkBox, and textView in recyclerView, I want to get the value on ‘editText, checkBox and textView, but i try to get editText only the last row i can get the value. help me to fix this.

my listAdapter:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ReceiveActivity.ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
        {

            holder.idQues.setText(dataList.get(position).getId());
            holder.textQues.setText(dataList.get(position).getDescription());

           btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    int listSize = dataList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i<listSize; i++){
                        String note = holder.txtPart.getText().toString();
                        list.add(note);
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                        Log.e(TAG,"dataedit: "+ list.get(i));
                    }
                    //Log.e(TAG,"cek data name: "+txtPICName+" title "+txtPICTitle+" email "+txtPICEmail+" ktp "+encodedImageKtp);

                }
            });

        }
```

my recyclerview_items

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/idPart"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:minWidth="105dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/partQue"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/partChk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:buttonTint="@color/black_overlay"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/partEdt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black_overlay"/>
```

i want to set data to array and show in log.

Comment: You have RecyclerView. Every item has 4 elements (`TextView`, `TextView`, `CheckBox` and `EditText`). Your plan is to display elements to the console, right? But WHEN would you like to display it? And WHAT? All of the items?

Comment: i have Button on the layout, i want to get the value when this action 
btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}

Comment: Which `value`? Are you clicking `Button`, and printing RecyclerView content to the console?

Comment: this section 
`ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    int listSize = dataList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i<listSize; i++){
                        String note = holder.txtPart.getText().toString();
                        list.add(note);
                    }

                    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                        Log.e(TAG,"dataedit: "+ list.get(i));
                    }`